# Правильно ли я проверяю цифровую подпись у исполняемого файла?

Tags: c#

Есть задача проверить наличие цифровой подписи и ее корректность, но в моем случае почему то, если подпись найдена, то она всегда не корректна, хотя я только тестирую алгоритмом sha1, а подписи могут быть сделаны разными алгоритмами. Вопрос, правильно ли я  проверку делаю на наличие подписи и есть ли более универсальный способ? Вот мой код.

```
public List<info> PrintKeys(string rkey)
{
    var stroka = new List<info>();
    var F = "Цифровая подпись найдена ";
    var G = "Цифровая подпись корректна";
    var G0 = "Цифровая подпись не корректна";
    var tipzapuska = "Реестр";
    var rp = rkey;
    RegistryKey rk;
    X509Certificate2 theCertificate;

    using (rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(rp))
    {
        var e = rk.GetValueNames().Select(n => new
        {
            Name = n,
            Value = rk.GetValue(n),
            Exec = rk.GetValue(n).ToString().Split('"').Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).First()
        });

        foreach (var x in e)
        {
            string path = GetExePath(x.Exec);
            string CmParametrs = GetExeParametrs(x.Exec);
            var icon1 = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path).ToBitmap();

            try
            {
                var theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(x.Exec);
                theCertificate = new X509Certificate2(theSigner);
                // проверяем на валидность
                var mashash = theCertificate.GetCertHash(); // хеш из сертификата файла в sha1
                var fileSha1 = GetSha1Hash(path); // получаем хеш файла в sha1

                // сравниваем два массива
                var bEqual = false;
                if (fileSha1.Length == mashash.Length)
                {
                    var i = 0;
                    while (i < fileSha1.Length && fileSha1[i] == mashash[i]) i += 1;
                    if (i == fileSha1.Length) bEqual = true;
                }

                // готовим строку
                if (bEqual)
                    stroka.Add(new info
                    {
                        A = icon1,
                        F1 = F,
                        G1 = G,
                        Namefile1 = x.Name,
                        Path1 = path,
                        Company = theCertificate.Issuer,
                        TipZapuska = tipzapuska
                    });
                //                           
                stroka.Add(new info
                {
                    A = icon1,
                    F1 = F,
                    G1 = G0,
                    Namefile1 = x.Name,
                    Path1 = path,
                    Company = theCertificate.Issuer,
                    TipZapuska = tipzapuska
                });
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                stroka.Add(new info
                {
                    A = icon1,
                    F1 = "Цифровая подпись отсутсвует",
                    G1 = "Цифровая подпись отсутсвует",
                    Namefile1 = x.Name,
                    Path1 = path,
                    TipZapuska = tipzapuska
                });
            }
        }
    }

    return stroka;
}

// local mashin
public class info
{
    public Bitmap A { get; set; } // иконка файла
    public string Namefile1 { get; set; } //Имя исполняемого файла.
    public string C1 { get; set; } //Параметры командной строки для запуска файла.
    public string Path1 { get; set; } // путь
    public string F1 { get; set; } //Флаг наличия цифровой подписи.
    public string G1 { get; set; } //Флаг корректности цифровой подписи
    public string Company { get; set; } //Информация о компании
    public string TipZapuska { get; set; }
}

public byte[] GetSha1Hash(string filePath)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
        return sha.ComputeHash(fs).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Для проверки цифровой подписи есть готовый API - WinVerifyTrust. Посмотрите примеры на C# - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596327/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-signed-in-c и https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust